# How can I test the -> C operator using a struct that allows me to access a struct's field?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

I'm trying to test the `->` operator, but I can't seem to do that, because when I execute the following program and feed the input with a stream, the program stops working.

**Note1: I get a warning before compiling, it says that:**

> format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type
>   'int' [-Wformat=]

**Note2: if I omit the line `printf("%s\n", *(&home1)->name )`, it works just fine, and actually prints whatever I wrote.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct home_type {
    char name[30] ;
}home;

int main (void) {
    home home1 ;
    char name[30] ;
    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);
    strcpy( home1.name, name) ;
    printf("%s\n", home1.name ) ;
    printf("%s\n", *(&home1)->name ) ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s\n", &(&home1)->name[0]);`........ ;)

Comment: note: `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", name);` fails if they press Enter without anything else beforehand, and you will fall through to `strcpy`ing an uninitialized string

Comment: Remember that `->` has the `*` already built in, so you don't need another one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to drop the `*` (i.e. not dereference):

```
printf("%s\n", (&home1)->name );
```

The member `name` is an array which gets converted into a pointer (`char*`) when passing to `printf()`. However, when you dereference it, it's just a single `char` that you pass.
Obviously, it doesn't match with what `printf()` expects for the format `%s`.

See: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/4389800)

Comment: <blockquote>The member name name is an array which gets converted into a pointer (char*)</blockquote>

what is `char*` ? I only know * as a dereference operator which access to the content of a memory address, and why does the dereference operator convert it to a single char? I mean, I understand the fact that the `*` in `*(&home1)->name` is redundant (thanks)... is it because the actual content I'm accesing is the first element of the vector `name`?

Comment: @newbie `char*` the type of the 2nd argument that pass (after *decay* - see the link). `->` is implies the struct is a pointer (`&home`). But the `*`(dereference) is applied to the member `name` which is an array. Dereferencing it gives `name[0]` (the first char in `name`). May be, try the same without using a struct if that makes it easier to understand: `char name[30]; scanf("%s", name);` and then see `printf("%s", name);` vs. `printf("%s", *name);`.

Comment: thank you so much... I was just checking that link, I haven't seen it till 10 seconds ago. Actually using the * with the `name` and with your and others' help, helped me understand the `->` and the `*` operators a little better, and even what the `printf()` function actually does.

Comment: OMG... I just realised about the associativity from right to left of the `*`, and that the parenthesis that wrap `&home` make that precedence higher, and `->` has higher precedence than `*`, so the `*` affects the actual char[], which I guess by default is the first ([0]) element.

Comment: @newbie or, a value of type `array of N` will in most context (including, if preceded by `*`, or passed as an argument to a function), decay into a *`pointer to N`* that points to the first element of the array.

Comment: it's more general than I was thinking?
so, an array (of a given type), will decay [for historical memory needs] in several contexts into a pointer (of a given type) that points to the first element of that array. what about the rest of the elements of that array? I will play a little, and see how I can access to them, but I'm guessing they're in consecutive positions in memory(?).

Answer (score 6):

Remove `*` and it works. Your code `*(&home1)->name` is analogous to `*(home1.name)` e.g. instead of passing the pointer to the first character, it passes the value of the first `char` in `name`; due to default argument promotions, that value is converted into an `int`.

Thus:

```
printf("%s\n", (&home1)->name );
```

should work; however you don't need `->` here; `->` is now just a shortcut for using a pointer-to-structs more conveniently; i.e. `(*ptr).name` into a more palatable `ptr->name`; as `home` is already a `struct` and not just a pointer to struct, you should use the `.` instead.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I was just trying to see how did the `->` operator works in a trivial example.

Answer (score 5):

Operators `->` and `.` are interchangeable:

- `obj.field` is the same as `(&obj)->field`
- `ptr->field` is the same as `(*ptr).field`

Note that you have added an asterisk to the result of `(&home1)->name`, which produces a `char`. Since `printf` is a variable-argument function, `char` is promoted to `int` during the call, explaining the warning.

When you pass an `int` for a parameter expecting a pointer, undefined behavior happens; in your case, the program crashes. Removing the dereference operator `*` will fix this problem.

Answer (score 5):

`(&home1)->name` is the member array. `*(&home1)->name` is a dereference on the member array which because of array decay is equivalent to `(&home1)->name[0]`. This has type `char`. Passing a `char` through the `...` of a variadic function such as `printf` promotes it to `int` (`...` causes [default argument promotions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6) to apply).